# ng-click swap out button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When a user clicks on "Save Changes" I'm wanting to change the inner copy to "Confirm Changes" and then once they confirm the submit button works as per.

I'm unsure of how to achieve this using angular.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p>
                            <button type="submit" class="vfnz-submit">Save changes</button>
                            <a ng-href="#/huntgroups/" class="vfnz-reset">Cancel</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ar14/kkc0dums/2/

You can make a directive as an attribute for your button:

```
//Make an attribute called confirm that can be added to any html element
myApp.directive('confirm', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // It can only be used as an attribute
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            //On click make the changes
            elem.on('click', function() {
                elem.attr('type','submit');
                elem.html('Confirm Changes');  
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Once clicked it'll change the inner html and add the `type="submit"` to the button.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I didn't test the submit functionality.

Comment: I will, just testing submitting now.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two buttons, one shown at a time depending on the truthy-ness of a $scope variable.

```
<button ng-show="!confirm" ng-click="toggleConfirm()" class="vfnz-submit">Save Changes</button>
<button ng-show="confirm" ng-click="toggleConfirm()" class="vfnz-submit">Confirm Changes</button>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have one button and just swap out the content and add another class for the "active" state?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure about the behavior of it being a `type="submit"` without trying it.

Comment: the toggleConfirm() - is this a function I will need within a directive to handle further logic?

Comment: You can put it in a controller

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all within the view, if you so wish:

```
<button ng-hide="{boolVar}" ng-click="{boolVar}=true">></button>
<button ng-show="{boolVar}" ng-click="{boolVar}=false"></button>
```